# What is the proper way to enable a normal user to shutdown, halt or reboot the computer?

Tags: linux, shutdown, reboot

My dirty solution is to `chmod +s /sbin/shutdown`. It works but this is probably not good practice and insecure. Moreover after some system updates the suid bit gets reset. What would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: i usually do `sudo shutdown now -h`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All users? Or a selected subset of them? Will they use the computer locally or also remotely (e.g. via ssh).

In case of a few users who also work remotely **sudo** will work fine. See [this link](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_allow_non-super_users_to_shutdown_computer_in_Linux) for details.

If they are logging in locally and via a GUI then there are better options. E.g. capturing the three finger salute via init and letting that trigger a 1 minute delayed shutdown. It has been ages since I set that up though, so I skipping on the details for that.  (I used that back when Slackware 3 was modern)

Comment: Either a single user or a group such as %users. The idea is to avoid using `sudo` every time and entering passwords. According to the link you posted a line in sudoers like `%users ALL=NOPASSWD:/sbin/shutdown` is probably all I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your `shutdown` accepts the `-a` switch (check with `shutdown --help`), you can do the following:

- Add the users that should be able to shut the system down to `/etc/shutdown.allow`.

  Example:

  ```
  userA
  userB
  ```
- Shut the system down using the `-a` switch.

  Example:

  ```
  shutdown -a -h now
  ```

Source: [UNIX man pages : shutdown (8)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?shutdown+8)

Comment: looks like my version of `shutdown` (generic Linux of the -buntu family) does not support the `-a` option. Looks like the expected way is to create a %shutdown group which would include the users who need to shutdown and then reference that in the sudoers file.

Answer (score 1):

I use  SL 6.4. It  has user version of poweroff, halt, reboot provided by usermode package. I can shutdown, reboot as a normal user (from the command line as well)

```
    $ which {poweroff,reboot,halt}
    /usr/bin/poweroff
    /usr/bin/reboot
    /usr/bin/halt

    rpm -qf $(which poweroff reboot halt)
    usermode-1.102-3.el6.x86_64
    usermode-1.102-3.el6.x86_64
    usermode-1.102-3.el6.x86_64
```

As root

```
    # which {poweroff,reboot,halt}
    /sbin/poweroff
    /sbin/reboot
    /sbin/halt

    # rpm -qf $(which poweroff reboot halt)
    upstart-0.6.5-12.el6.x86_64
    upstart-0.6.5-12.el6.x86_64
    upstart-0.6.5-12.el6.x86_64
```